# One dimensional interference of oscillations

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, interference

recently I learned about the one dimensional interference of oscillations. The equations make sense where each of the motion equations e.g. $x(t) = A\exp(-i\omega t)$ (where $A$ is the Amplitude, $\omega$ is the angular velocity, $t$ is the time ) are simply added together linearly. But I am having trouble imagining it as, for example, two springs with different frequencies, amplitudes and phase shifts whose oscillations are added together. How would such a system work? Will the springs be connected end-to-end and will their motions eventually become the same or can they actually continue to oscillate at their own frequencies etc. while they are connected(if they should be connected at all?)

I hope I haven't phrased my questions in such a way that causes confusions but if so, do let me know and I will try other explainations!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition of sinusoidal oscillations is is usually demonstrated with voltages generated by signal generators and applied to the y-inputs of an oscilloscope with an *addition* facility! But this is not what you want?

With springs, I think that I'd set the two mass-spring systems side-by-side but some distance apart, so each could oscillate independently. Then I'd rest (not fix) a light rod on the two masses, with some arrangement to stop it falling off, but allowing it some sideways play. Then I'd set the masses oscillating. If one has vertical displacement $x_1(t)$ and the other, $x_2(t)$, then the middle of the rod will have vertical displacement $\frac 12 [x_1(t)+x_2(t)]$.

You could have the best (or worst) of both worlds by fixing identical bar magnets, with their axes vertical, to the masses on the springs. You'd put identical (stationary) coils, with axes vertical, underneath the magnets, so that the magnets, when they move, induce emfs in the coils. The voltage across the coils, connected in series, will be proportional to the sum of the velocities of the oscillating masses, for small amplitude oscillations. Provided that the voltmeter (or oscilloscope) has a high impedance input, the coils won't affect the oscillations.